# AngularJs ui-router access direct trought url param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Currently I'm building a webApp and I'd like to create a link to have direct access to a specific user, city or company. For example:

- myapp.com/cityName
- myapp.com/user321
- myapp.com/BusinessName

I can set the proper name, id, or whatever the param is. But the problem is when I try to access this state or other page, they have conflict. For example, if I try to go to the homepage, which has this configuration:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/Welcome',
    //..other configs
})
```

The router try to get the url as a param and send the user to the page of the company, user or city.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

---

#### Edit:

Currently, to avoid this conflict, I'm using my routing like this:

```
.state('city', {
    url: '/City/:cityName',
    //..other configs
})
```

But I'd like, if possible, to use like this:

```
.state('city', {
    url: '/:cityName',
    //..other configs
})
```

Because I want users to be able to access the page by typing the name direct on the url.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you probably want something like this.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/welcome',
    //..other configs 
})
.state('cities', {
    url: '/cities/:parameter'
})
```

This way you remove the conflict.

---

Update: You could also make an array with excluded parameters, if the parameter is not in the excluded list, redirect to a different state.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/:slug',
    //..other configs 
})
.state('cities', {
    url: '/cities/:slug'
})

var excludedWords = ['welcome', 'homepage'];
$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function(event) {
    if(excludedWords.indexOf($stateParams.slug) !== -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('cities', $stateParams);
    } 
});
```

This way, if a user enters /welcome, he/she won't get redirected to the /cities/welcome page, but if he/she enters /newyork he/she will be redirected to /cities/newyork

Comment: Kind of... Because i want users to be able to access the web by typing in the url the name of their city, or the company they are looking for. For example, if I want to go to the page of company 'JJshoes', then i just type it: myapp.com/JJshoes , understand?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade I've updated my code, this is all from the top of my head so there could be a few mistakes in it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it in a bit and get back to you! Thanks.